# Getting "Expected string, got None" error on Model.get_by_id()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When running this code, with the *same site_id*:

```
int_id= int(self.request.get("site_id"))
site_draft = SiteDraft.get_by_id(int_id)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
INFO     2016-06-27 12:39:19,040 module.py:788] minisites: "GET /edit/5891733057437696 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yuri\Documents\WiseStamp\Server\minisites\web\pages\edit_site.py", line 21, in get
    self.post(args)
  File "C:\Users\Yuri\Documents\WiseStamp\Server\minisites\web\pages\edit_site.py", line 44, in post
    site_draft = SiteDraft.get_by_id(int_id)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\utils.py", line 160, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 3602, in _get_by_id
    return cls._get_by_id_async(id, parent=parent, **ctx_options).get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\tasklets.py", line 378, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\tasklets.py", line 425, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.send(val)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\context.py", line 765, in get
    pbs = entity._to_pb(set_key=False).SerializePartialToString()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 3167, in _to_pb
    prop._serialize(self, pb, projection=self._projection)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1422, in _serialize
    values = self._get_base_value_unwrapped_as_list(entity)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1192, in _get_base_value_unwrapped_as_list
    wrapped = self._get_base_value(entity)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1180, in _get_base_value
    return self._apply_to_values(entity, self._opt_call_to_base_type)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1352, in _apply_to_values
    value[:] = map(function, value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1234, in _opt_call_to_base_type
    value = _BaseValue(self._call_to_base_type(value))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1255, in _call_to_base_type
    return call(value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1331, in call
    newvalue = method(self, value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 1781, in _validate
    (value,))
BadValueError: Expected string, got None
```

It used to work a day ago, but now it works only 20% of the time (which is also weird - it seems to be working some times). What's even weirder that I'm providing an `int` as the `site_id`, but it tells me it gets a `None`.

Please advise.

Comment: It would seem that site_id is not defined in request object. I would suggest you start by logging the site_id in the request.

Comment: Hi @TimHoffman the site_id is indeed defined, it would break the int casting otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Just print `site_id`'s value (and type) between your 2 statements - the `get_by_id()` flexibility (accepting strings, ints and longs) can play tricks when it comes to the error messages it spews out (for improperly formatted requests for example, accidental or not). Personally I'd add (a lot) more checks for request values before feeding them into my DB...

Comment: JUst re-checking your stacktrace I don't think the problem is with your id.  Please show the model of SiteDraft and have you recently added/changed the type of a property defined in the SiteDraft model.  My bet is some pre-existing entities are not compliant with the current model. Notice the error is   in `_to_pb` after it's retreived something from the datastore.

Comment: @TimHoffman this was the issue exactly. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As request

Looking at the stack trace in detail and paying attention to the operations performed,

we see

```
 _get_by_id
 get_result
 _help_tasklet_al
 get
 _to_pb
 _serialize
 _get_base_value
_get_base_value
_apply_to_values
_opt_call_to_base
_call_to_base_type
call
_validate


BadValueError: Expected string, got None
```

We see that the path of execution was inside `_get_by_id` and it was processing get_result.  So an entity has been retrieved. Looking further down we see that the code is in fact validating the values retrieved and fails in the `_validate` call with the  BadValueError: Expected string, got None

How does one get a bad value in an existing entity.  Typically it is as a result of changing the model where you either

- added a new required property and not updating existing entities.,
- changed the type of an existing property
- added a validator to a property and not made existing entities compliant.

When you change Models it is important to consider entity migration.

Cheers

T

Comment: Superb debugging, Tim